# Random number guessing game throws error: > or < cannot be used between str and int

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

I have the following code for a random number guessing game:

```
import random
number = random.randint(1,100)

name = input('Hi, Whats your name?')
print ("Well", name, "i am thinking of a number between 1 and 100, take a guess")


guess1 = input()
if guess1 == number:
    print ("Good job, you got it!")
while guess1 != number:
    if guess1 > number:
        print ('your guess is too high')
    if guess1 < number:
        print ('your guess is too low')
```

which throws the error that `>` or `<` cannot be used between `str` and `int`.

What should I do so it doesn't trigger that error?

Comment: You are asking for the core of the assignment. What have you tried and where did you fail?

Comment: And as a comment, you better include the input text inside the input: `myName = input('Hello! What is your name? ')` to prevent the linefeed following the `print` statement.

Comment: upvoting this question because it's a common mistake and it appears in google when searching "python number guessing game", which allows to close others as duplicates

Answer (score 3):

There are two errors in your code.

1. You need to convert the input for guess1 from a string (by default) to an integer before you can compare it to the number (an integer).
2. The while loop will never stop since you are not letting the user input another value.

Try this:

```
import random
number = random.randint(1,100)

name = input('Hi, Whats your name?')
print ("Well", name, "i am thinking of a number between 1 and 100, take a guess")

guess1 = int(input()) # convert input from string to integer

while guess1 != number:
    if guess1 > number:
        print ('your guess is too high. Try again.')
    elif guess1 < number:
        print ('your guess is too low. Try again.')

    guess1 = int(input()) # asks user to take another guess

print("Good job, you got it!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a **while** loop here - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

The logic should be:

```
answer_is_correct = False

while not answer_is_correct :

    Keep receiving input until answer is correct
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you:

```
import random
myname = input('Hello, what is your name?')
print('Well',myname,'am thinking of a number between 1 and 100')
number = random.randint(1,100)
guess = 0
while guess < 4:
    guess_number = int(input('Enter a number:'))
    guess += 1
    if guess_number < number:
        print('Your guess is to low') 
    if guess_number > number:
        print('Your guess is to high')
    if guess_number == number:
        print('Your guess is correct the number is',number)
        break
    if guess == 4:
        break
print('The number i was thinking of is',number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

print("you wanna guess a number between A to B and time of guess:")
A = int(input("A:"))
B = int(input("B:"))
time = int(input("time:"))
x = randint(1, 10)
print(x)

while time != 0:
    num = int(input("Enter: "))
    time -= 1
    if num == x:
        print("BLA BLA BLA")
        break
    print("NOPE !")
    if time == 0:
        print("game over")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Code in Python 3 for guessing game:

```
import random

def guessGame():

    while True:
        while True:
            try:
                low, high = map(int,input("Enter a lower number and a higher numer for your game.").split())
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Enter valid numbers please.")

        if low > high:
            print("The lower number can't be greater then the higher number.")
        elif low+10 >= high:
            print("At least lower number must be 10 less then the higher number")
        else:
            break

    find_me = random.randint(low,high)
    print("You have 6 chances to find the number...")
    chances = 6
    flag = 0
    while chances:
        chances-=1 
        guess = int(input("Enter your guess : "))
        if guess<high and guess>low:
            if guess < find_me:
                print("The number you have entered a number less then the predicted number.",end="//")
                print("{0} chances left.".format(chances))
            elif guess > find_me:
                print("The number you have entered a number greater then the predicted number.",end="//")
                print("{0} chances left.".format(chances))
            else:
                print("Congrats!! you have succesfully guessed the right answer.")
                return

        else:
            print("You must not input number out of range")
            print("{0} chances left.".format(chances))

    print("The predicted number was {0}".format(find_me))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can conditions within the while loop to check if its right. It can be done the following way.

```
import random

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 100)
print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.')
inputNumber = int(raw_input('Enter the number')
while inputNumber != number:
      print "Sorry wrong number , try again"
      inputNumber = int(raw_input('Enter the number')
print "Congrats!"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from random import *

def play_game():
    print("Let's play a number guessing game")
    # Selecting a random number between 1 and 100
    number = randint(1, 100)
    choice = int(input("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100. Could you guess what it is? "))

    # Guide the user towards the right guess
    # Loop will continue until user guesses the right number
    while choice != number:
        if choice < number:
            choice = int(input("Too low. Can you try again? "))
        elif choice > number:
            choice = int(input("Too high. Can you try again? "))
    continue_game = input("You guessed it right! Would you like to play it again? (Y/N) ")

    # Restart the game if user wishes to play again
    if continue_game == "Y":
        print("--" * 42)
        play_game()
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing :)")
        exit(0)

play_game()
```